# Request ready state always returns 0?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

I am new to JavaScript and trying to play with some Ajax to dynamically load HTML into a `<div>` element.  I have a PHP page that spits out a JSON with the HTML needed to insert into the `<div>`.  I have been testing and cannot get the call to work.  I started to do alerts on my readystate, and I get 0 and then nothing else.  From my understanding, the function `sendData()` should be called every time the readystate changes, but it appears to only do it once, or the readystate never changes, so it only gets called once...?

This is my PHP

```
<?php
    $array['html'] = '<p>hello, menu here</p>';
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Veolia Water - Solutions and Technologies Dashboard</title>  
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />    
<meta name="description" content="Veolia Water - Dashboard"/>
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta author="Nathan Sizemore"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/stylo.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./js/dashboard.js"></script>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
var request;
window.onload = function() 
{
     load_menu();
}

//Load menu function
function load_menu()
{   
    request = getHTTPObject();
    alert(request.readyState);
    request.onreadystatechange = sendData();
    request.open("GET", "./php/menu.php", true);
    request.send(null);
}

function getHTTPObject()
{
    var xhr = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    {
        try
        {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                xhr = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return xhr;
}

function sendData()
{
    alert(request.readyState);
    // if request object received response
    if (request.readyState == 4)
    {
        var json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML = json.html;
        alert(json.html);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
request.onreadystatechange = sendData;
```

Note that the `()` are removed from `sendData()`

What you had before was immediately executing `sendData` and returning its result to `onreadystatechange`. Since nothing is actually `return`ed, the value is `undefined`. It wasn't actually setting anything to `onreadystatechange` and therefore not actually executing anything when the `state` changes. The `onreadystatechange` property expects a reference to a function...which is exactly what `sendData` is.

In your code, since `sendData` was executed once (accidentally), the state reported is 0 (the XHR's initial state).

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
request.onreadystatechange = sendData();
```

To this

```
request.onreadystatechange = sendData;
```

The first code calls `sendData` and assigns the result as the handler.
The second one assigns the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
request.onreadystatechange = sendData();
```

should be

```
request.onreadystatechange = sendData;
```

You're calling `sendData` immediately and using the *result* of that function as the listener, rather than using the function itself.

Comment: JavaScript and callback things are still fuzzy to me, I figured that to call the function, I needed the `()` like I do in other languages.  This will take getting used to...